# Inline commit notes in gist?

Tags: gist

Is there any way to make inline commit notes on gists?

It's possible to achieve this sort of functionality, e.g. for code review, on any normal github repository (see http://astrofrog.github.io/blog/2013/04/10/how-to-conduct-a-full-code-review-on-github/).  What about on gist?

Answer (score -1):

No.

You can build a site for this via gist API, though.